# Can't open .class file

Tags: java

My professor had us download a .class file for a project. I put it in the src folder but I can't open the class. It says "can't open, no sources". How do I fix this?

Currently using netbeans 8.2 if it matters.

Comment: Are you meant to open / edit it or just use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use a .class file with .java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510564/how-to-use-a-class-file-with-java-files)

Comment: we're meant to use it

Comment: the teacher should explain the difference between source (\*.java) and compiled (\*.class) files first. Also how these are *used*.

Comment: I tried those methods and they didn't work. I'm supposed be able to use it and view it.

Comment: "those methods"? edit the question and describe what you have tried. And the teacher must provide the fully qualified name of the class(es) (package name and class name) and how to use it. To view a class file you need some kind of decompiler (javap (comes with JDK), JAD, ...) - but kind of strange, if the professor wants you to view the class, he should have provided the source code

Comment: *"I'm supposed be able to use it and view it."*  - If your teacher has given you a just ".class" file then I'm pretty sure he / she does not want you to view it.   (If you need to view it, ask your teacher for the ".java" file!)

Comment: A [.class file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) contains **compiled code**. You can use its contained methods if you place the file somewhere the runtime can find it.

Answer (score 0):

A class file is already compiled.. you can only open a .java file. 
Otherwise you have to decompile the class file